# (^|)(Get|Total|Aggregated|Summary|Data|Report) - #NamingIsHard

Tags: vba, excel

The following is the top-level procedure for aggregating, analysing and reporting my company's submitted business from 2015 - present. Reviewing the entire project is unfeasible, so I am just seeking opinions on Variable/Method naming and general readability.

For reference, `CLS_Data_Report` is a class I built specifically to handle 2-dimensional data array operations (adding, merging, filtering, printing etc.).

---

Based just on the following, is it clear what the various parts of the procedure are doing?

Are there any code smells?

Is the naming too repetitive?

```
Public Sub GenerateDirectorsReport()

    StoreApplicationSettings
    DisableApplicationSettings

    Set WbSubsheet2015 = GetWorkbook(SUBSHEET_2015_FILENAME, SUBSHEET_2015_FILEPATH)
    Set WbSubsheet2016 = GetWorkbook(SUBSHEET_2016_FILENAME, SUBSHEET_2016_FILEPATH)

    Dim aggregatedSubsheetDataReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set aggregatedSubsheetDataReport = GetAggregatedSubsheetData(WbSubsheet2015, WbSubsheet2016)
    wsAggregatedData.Cells.Clear
    aggregatedSubsheetDataReport.PrintToWorksheet wsAggregatedData.Cells(1, 1)

    '/============================================================================================================================================================

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wsSummaryReports

    ws.Cells.Clear

    Dim printRow As Long, printCol As Long
    printRow = 2
    printCol = 2

    Dim clientInvestmentReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set clientInvestmentReport = GetClientInvestmentReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport)
    clientInvestmentReport.PrintToWorksheet ws.Cells(printRow, printCol)
    FormatPrintedAdviserReport clientInvestmentReport.printRange

    printRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, printCol).End(xlUp).row + 2

    Dim totalOngoingReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set totalOngoingReport = GetTotalOngoingReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport)
    totalOngoingReport.PrintToWorksheet ws.Cells(printRow, printCol)
    FormatPrintedAdviserReport totalOngoingReport.printRange

    printRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, printCol).End(xlUp).row + 2

    Dim commissionReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set commissionReport = GetCommissionReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport)
    commissionReport.PrintToWorksheet ws.Cells(printRow, printCol)
    FormatPrintedCommissionReport commissionReport.printRange

    '/============================================================================================================================================================

    wsOngoingData.Cells.Clear
    wsOngoingData.Activate

    totalOngoingReport.PrintToWorksheet wsOngoingData.Cells(1, 1)
    FormatPrintedAdviserReport totalOngoingReport.printRange

    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

'/============================================================================================================================================================

    CreateAndPrintAllProviderReports aggregatedSubsheetDataReport

'/============================================================================================================================================================

    '/ The following are not necessary to final operation, but are used to manually observe and double-check the various filterings of the aggregated data.        

    Dim jonHusseyNameStrings As Collection
    Set jonHusseyNameStrings = NameStringsCollectionFromAdviser(JonHussey)
    Dim jonHusseyAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set jonHusseyAdviserReport = GetFilteredDataReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport, ADVISER_HEADER, EqualTo, jonHusseyNameStrings, keep)
    wsJonHussey.Cells.Clear
    jonHusseyAdviserReport.PrintToWorksheet wsJonHussey.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim martinCotterNameStrings As Collection
    Set martinCotterNameStrings = NameStringsCollectionFromAdviser(MartinCotter)
    Dim martinCotterAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set martinCotterAdviserReport = GetFilteredDataReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport, ADVISER_HEADER, EqualTo, martinCotterNameStrings, keep)
    wsMartinCotter.Cells.Clear
    martinCotterAdviserReport.PrintToWorksheet wsMartinCotter.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim jonathanBlairNameStrings As Collection
    Set jonathanBlairNameStrings = NameStringsCollectionFromAdviser(JonathanBlair)
    Dim jonathanBlairAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set jonathanBlairAdviserReport = GetFilteredDataReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport, ADVISER_HEADER, EqualTo, jonathanBlairNameStrings, keep)
    wsJonathanBlair.Cells.Clear
    jonathanBlairAdviserReport.PrintToWorksheet wsJonathanBlair.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim jeremySmithNameStrings As Collection
    Set jeremySmithNameStrings = NameStringsCollectionFromAdviser(JeremySmith)
    Dim jeremySmithAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set jeremySmithAdviserReport = GetFilteredDataReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport, ADVISER_HEADER, EqualTo, jeremySmithNameStrings, keep)
    wsJeremySmith.Cells.Clear
    jeremySmithAdviserReport.PrintToWorksheet wsJeremySmith.Cells(1, 1)

    '/============================================================================================================================================================

    Dim investmentCodenameStrings As Collection
    Set investmentCodenameStrings = GetInvestmentCodenameStrings(WbSubsheet2015, WbSubsheet2016)
    Dim investmentDataReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set investmentDataReport = GetFilteredDataReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport, SOURCE_WORKSHEET_HEADER, EqualTo, investmentCodenameStrings, keep)
    wsInvestmentReport.Cells.Clear
    investmentDataReport.PrintToWorksheet wsInvestmentReport.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim ongoingCodenameStrings As Collection
    Set ongoingCodenameStrings = GetOngoingCodenameStrings(WbSubsheet2015, WbSubsheet2016)
    Dim totalOngoingDataReport As CLS_Data_Report
    Set totalOngoingDataReport = GetFilteredDataReport(aggregatedSubsheetDataReport, SOURCE_WORKSHEET_HEADER, EqualTo, ongoingCodenameStrings, keep)
    wsOngoingReport.Cells.Clear
    totalOngoingDataReport.PrintToWorksheet wsOngoingReport.Cells(1, 1)

    '/============================================================================================================================================================

    CloseWorkbook WbSubsheet2015
    CloseWorkbook WbSubsheet2016

    RestoreApplicationSettings

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the naming too repetitive? Let's take a look at your variables

```
Dim aggregatedSubsheetDataReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim clientInvestmentReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim commissionReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim investmentCodenameStrings As Collection
Dim investmentDataReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim jeremySmithAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim jeremySmithNameStrings As Collection
Dim jonathanBlairAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim jonathanBlairNameStrings As Collection
Dim jonHusseyAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim jonHusseyNameStrings As Collection
Dim martinCotterAdviserReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim martinCotterNameStrings As Collection
Dim ongoingCodenameStrings As Collection
Dim printRow As Long, printCol As Long
Dim totalOngoingDataReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim totalOngoingReport As CLS_Data_Report
Dim ws As Worksheet
```

Seems repetitive, but it's also pretty clear. I'd drop the `strings` out of the names and drop the `adviser` as well.

You might want to make  a better distinction between `totalOngoingReport` and `totalOngoingDataReport`

<sup>and maybe deal with that little `ws` variable</sup>

---

Let me take a look at the names of the calls you're making

```
CloseWorkBook
CreateAndPrintAllProviderReports
FormatPrintedAdviserReport
FormatPrintedCommissionReport
.PrintToWorksheet
```

Not very repetitive there either, even combining with the other variables. It probably looks a little repetitive or cluttered - but I really don't think it is.